# SwiftUI Rotate screen make modal don’t longer dismiss itself

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a bug on SwiftUI, when I rotate my device the modal don't longer dismiss, the problem here is that only happen on the device on the simulator works well also on my iPad.

```
import SwiftUI

struct modalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }){
            Text("close")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showModal.toggle()
        }){
            Text("modal")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal, content: {
            modalView()
        })
    }
}
```

[Bug on my device][1]

i have this problem since iOS 13
im currently on iOS 14.2 beta
and Xcode 12 GM
[1]: https://twitter.com/MisaelLandero/status/1306953785651142656?s=20

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @State private var showModal = false

  // If you are getting the "can only present once" issue, add this here.
  // Fixes the problem, but not sure why; feel free to edit/explain below.
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode


  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.showModal = true
    }) {
        Text("Show modal")
    }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
        ModalView()
    }
  }
}


struct ModalView: View {

  @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

  var body: some View {
    Group {
      Text("Modal view")
      Button(action: {
         self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      }) {
        Text("Dismiss")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks but I have the same bug, just on the iPhone btw in the iPad work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the problem, I was using a condition to show two different navigations views, that break the dismiss modal

```
if self.sizeClass == .compact{
NavigationViewForiPhone()
} else {
NavigationViewForiPad()
}
```

looks like thats the problem cuz my view is reload